# Proving that any permutation in $S_n$ can be written as a product of disjoint cycles

Tags: finite-groups, permutations, proof-verification, symmetric-groups

I have attempted a proof of this, but upon looking at my notes, I feel it might be incorrect: it is noticeably simpler than the one in my notes.

**Proposition:** any permutation in $S_n$ can be written as a product of disjoint cycles.

*Proof (attempt):* $s\in S_n$. Let $\langle s\rangle$ act on $X=\{1,\cdots,n\}$. Define $x\sim x'\iff x'\in\text{Orb}(x)$ for $x,x'\in X:$ this is clearly an equivalent relation, hence the orbits partition $X$. Each orbit corresponds a cycle in $s$, so we are done.

Does this hold, or have I missed something vital?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The proof is indeed correct. There is a nice intuition behind this:

You can interpret a permutation as a directed graph: The nodes are the numbers $1,\dots,n$ and there is an arrow from $a$ to $b$ if the permutation $\pi$ maps $\pi(a)=b$. This is a functional graph and as the number of nodes is finite and the map is one-to-one, every node has exactly one in-edge and exactly one out-edge. It is clear that this graph must be a set of disjoint cycles (hence the name).

Of course this is only a picture to the proof, to show where it comes from. The proof is correct because we can easily check that $S_n$ indeed acts on $X$ and orbits are cycles.

---

EDIT: Someone requested a real picture, not only a sketch of the proof. So I add one showing the corresponding graph of the permutation $\left(\begin{eqnarray} 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10 \\ 8&6&5&9&3&10&4&7&1&2  \end{eqnarray}\right)$.

[image]

Comment: What happened to the picture that you mention in your last paragraph? Can it be linked or uploaded back?

Comment: @FrankMuer I meant a sketch, not a picture. Sorry for using the wrong word. I added a picture in order to make it correct.

Comment: Exquisite picture. Thanks a lot. Upvoted.  No problem. What'd you flesh it out with?

Comment: @FrankMuer Thanks, that's yEd graph editor.

Answer (score 7):

If, in proving this theorem, you have available the previously explained notion of group-actions and orbits, and if you have defined "cycles" in this manner, then yes your proof is valid. However, in the progression of a typical algebra course, this theorem is covered before those "tools" are available, hence the need for a more "complicated" proof.